# Can someone please explain to me how the pipe "|" character works in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I have this code:

```
 [a,b,[]]=[First,Second,Third|Fourth].
```

and it gives me the following output:

```
 First = a, Second = b, Third = Fourth, Fourth = [].
```

I'd like to know how `Third` got assigned to `Fourth`.

Comment: It didn't, they are just both empty lists and they are equal 'by accident'. I answered related question two days ago, maybe it can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478862/whats-the-difference-between-following-two-prolog-lists/19479189#19479189

Comment: Remember that the output isn't "assignments", it's "equivalencies". So the correct way to read that is `Third = Fourth = []`, or "`Third`, `Fourth`, and `[]` are equal to one another".

Comment: The answer/output you got was different: Simple answer substitutions are in a single line, and `Third = Fourth, Fourth = []` was in one line too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipe character is very similar to the "consing dot" in Lisp. The variable after the pipe takes the entire remainder of the corresponding list.

So, here we expect `Third` to bind to the explicitly given empty list in the data. But there is nothing after that and so `Fourth` also binds empty.

`Third` being bound to `Fourth` is just an indirect way of `Third` being bound to empty.

Comment: No offense, but I found it slightly humorous that you randomly assumed he knows "consing dot" from Lisp.

Comment: I don't know what "consing dot" from Lisp is haha. But I liked your explanation.

Comment: @zch I likewise found it slightly humorous that he randomly assumed someone out there knows what Prolog is.

Comment: Prolog has a kind of consing dot too, but syntactically it's expressed as a predicate:  `.(a,b)`.  In Lisp, `(a b c)` is equivalent to the fully dotted `(a . (b . (c . nil))`. The consing dot indicates that the following thing is a list, which forms the rest of this list. In the beginning, McCarthy used a binary dot notation. The idea that `(a . (b . (c . nil)))` can be condensed to `(a b c)` came later. And so, anyway, in a Lisp based pattern matcher, we might use `(foo bar . xyzzy)` as a counterpart to Prolog's `[foo, bar | xyzzy]`. So, the bar is like the consing dot, in some ways at least.

Answer (score 2):

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7559044/467473 for details on how Prolog lists are implemented.

Basically, a prolog list is a simple data structure. The empty list is denoted by the atom `[]`. A non-empty list is the structure `./2`. The left argument in this structure is the *head* of the list; the right argument is the *tail* of the list, which is another list (either the empty list `[]` or a non-empty list (`./2`).

The friendly list notation is just syntactic sugar on top of this. The expression `[H|T]` is *exactly* the same as the expression `.(H,T)`. The expression `[a,b|T]` is exactly the same as `.(a,.(b,T))`. And the expression `[a,b,c]` is exactly the same as `.(a,.(b,.(c,[])))`.